# IIS 7.5 broken, cannot connect to localhost, error 404

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, iis-7.5

Someone set up IIS 7.5 on my computer with a sample project. I created a new project and I wanted this new project to be accessible on the localhost (default port 80). I changed the Site (under Sites in the navigator) in the IIS Manager and now I can't do anything.

When I try to run the project from Visual Studio it opens successfully in the browser in "localhost/#somePort" but when I try to type in just "localhost" into the browser, I get a 404 Error.

Please, any ideas on how to fix this? I think maybe some default files for IIS were changed/corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually from Visual studio if it's an ASP.net project it will run from the Web Developer test engine (which is a mini iis that runs on a random port)... You need to publish the project to IIS or copy the compiled output to a folder that is within your IIS's site's directory path and change that folder to an application (from the iis mmc console, right clicking on the folder and selecting Change to Application, I believe...

I wasn't sure about the "localhost/#somePort" but i'm assuming I am getting what you meant ;)

Comment: isn't this the answer to this problem  ?

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the same problem.  Apparently changing the bindings changes only the default site / and not the child virtual applications.

I found this article -  http://www.carryoverbit.com/running-iis-on-localhost-only/

Incase the link is broken...

After editing the bindings in IISManager ("Edit Bindings..."), you need to use netsh and add 127.0.0.1 as a listener for http traffic.

Open command prompt (as admin)

```
netsh
netsh> http
netsh http> show iplisten 
(empty list is shown)
netsh http> add iplisten 127.0.0.1

IP address successfully added
```

Now use **iisreset** and everything should work.

Comment: Can be typed as a single command
`netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1`

Comment: This does not work and is a super wierd suggestion